# C#: Which is an already serializable collection (I mean, created from microsoft)

Tags: c#, serialization, collections

I need to serialize a collection, but I would like to know if there is any already serializable collection before taking code from third parts or write it by myself. I already implemented some serializable collection, but this is a stupid situation where I just need to pass an array of serializable classes to the clipboard and back from it (copy/paste).

Any suggestion on what should I use?

Comment: Plenty of collections (like List) are serializable, but the elements they store may or may not be. It's up to the element to understand how to serialize and deserialize itself.

Comment: That's why I wrote: *[...]pass an array of serializable classes[...]*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any class in the `System.Collections` or `System.Collections.Generic` namespace should be serializable. However, this doesn't mean that the content (or in the case of generics, `T` is serializable). This is visible with `Dictionary<K,V>`, as `KeyValuePair<K,V>` isn't directly serializable.

Comment: +1 for providing info about generic type that may not be serializable and may cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

I used `List<T>` before and it works great.

Comment: Mhh I'm having problem with it but maybe it's not connected to the list but to how I use clipboard methods